# Sliding blocks with pistons - can I delay the rising edge only?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a two-high row of 10-high blocks stacked on top of eachother, oriented like this with pistons on the sides:

```
[-> [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] .. <-]
[-> [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] .. <-]
```

The idea is to slide the blocks to one side when an input is on, and to the other when the input is off (likely by using torches besides the top piston on either side so they fire simultaneously). Slime blocks and multiple sticky pistons cannot help my situation here, part due to design and part due to the lack of space to work with.

My naive solutions tend to die on the fact that I need one side to get powered slightly later than the other unpowers. I looked at rising and falling edge detectors a bit, but in order to minimize the noise during shifting I'd prefer if one of the pistons stayed extended as opposed to speed-toggle. (Admittedly, I don't really have the real estate for rising edge and falling edge either.)

Is there a relatively simple/neat solution to *only* delaying the 'ON' (rising edge) signal, but leaving the 'OFF' (falling edge) alone?

Comment: This video might have something relevant: [Minecraft - Tutorial: Nether Wart Farm](http://youtu.be/gFUrAdep5kI?t=2m9s)

Comment: I knew I had seen something like it before, thanks. Problem with that is that it relies on the buttons timing and then a bunch of repeaters for the way back. I have either ON (I want all blocks slid to the left), or OFF (all blocks should be to the right). There's no builtin timing I can rely on, so to speak.

Comment: So you want it to be able to stay in the off state for an extended period of time? What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I basically wanted to have the pistons not push at the same time (preventing one from extending), while also minimizing the noise with a toggle (there's actually several of those walls in my build) by not having pistons retract needlessly. 'Pulsed' pistons get really noisy and annoy the crap out of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to have the pistons extended at all times, use a [pulse limiter](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pulse_circuit#Pulse_limiter) on each side.  Then pistons will only be "on" (i.e. extended) for a short period.

Update:  I assumed both sides were being triggered by a lever, and one side has a NOT GATE before the pulse limiter.

Comment: And then I'll still have the initial problem that both sides trigger at the exact same time (leaving the actual movement to be a toss-up of fate), bringing me back to my original situation where I'd have to make a rising edge and falling edge mechanism in my limited space and have to listen to the extra noise. :-/

Comment: But...... you indirectly inspired me for the way to solve the problem I was having... so simple that I feel stupid! Two repeaters of different timings onto an AND gate will shorten the time the pistons are activated. Probably can skip two repeaters too and use a comparator to boot to have a tiny 2x2 footprint solution. Will try that later. If it works, I'll give you the credit for inspiring me :-)

Comment: @Stigma Thanks for the credit.  updated answer to hopefully alleviate confusion on my design.  If you get a solution, post a screenshot, I think it would be quite interesting to see.

Comment: A screenshot is a pain due to the space constraints. It really is just an AND-gate on one side, and a NOT followed by an AND-gate on the other side. Trick is to have one of the AND inputs being one or two ticks slower than the other input. This will effectively shorten the 'ON' signal. Additionally, it may be necessary to slightly vary the timings on one side or another; I was also fighting diagonal powering of some pistons which complicated my situation considerably and as such I don't know to what degree my timings are dependable. I just messed around till it worked. xD

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do here is indeed a pulse limiter but between the lever and the rest of the circuit (the not gate on one side and the pulse limiter on the other side) you should make an ABBA gate:[image]

so they work both ways. this way you can switch it back an forth not only back